# OpenGL Bump Mapping not working

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, opengl, windows-7

I'm trying to apply a bump map to a 2D texture, from the code that I've seen in this tutorial: http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/simplebump/simplebump.html

I've changed the code to work with my setup (not using client states, drawing verticies with glVertex instead of glDrawElements etc...) but when I run the program, I get this output:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=cf02ea7

This is the code: (x,y,z,w,h,st are all valid values)

```
//Bind normal map to texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bump->texnum);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Bind normalisation cube map to texture unit 1
glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB, draw_ncm);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB);
glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);

//Set up texture environment to do (tex0 dot tex1)*color
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE_ARB);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB_ARB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB_ARB, GL_REPLACE);

glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE_ARB);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB_ARB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB_ARB, GL_DOT3_RGB_ARB);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE1_RGB_ARB, GL_PREVIOUS_ARB);

glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);

glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glTexCoord2f( st[0], st[1] );
glVertex3f( x, y, z );
glTexCoord2f( st[0], st[3] );
glVertex3f( x, y+h, z );
glTexCoord2f( st[2], st[3] );
glVertex3f( x+w, y+h, z );
glTexCoord2f( st[2], st[1] );
glVertex3f( x+w, y, z );
glEnd();

// texture pass
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, pic->texnum);
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glTexCoord2f( st[0], st[1] );
glVertex3f( x, y, z );
glTexCoord2f( st[0], st[3] );
glVertex3f( x, y+h, z );
glTexCoord2f( st[2], st[3] );
glVertex3f( x+w, y+h, z );
glTexCoord2f( st[2], st[1] );
glVertex3f( x+w, y, z );
glEnd();
```

Comment: Why are you bothering with glTexEnv? Just use shaders and be done with!

Answer (score 1):

Are you providing tangent vectors for the shader you're using? You'll need to give the shader access to a **tangent vector attribute** in order for this to work properly. You'll also need to define a **uniform for the normal map**. I can answer this in full when I get back home, but it's more involved than what you posted here. Also, what OpenGL core are you looking to comply with? 1.x? 2.x? 3.x/4.x?

Comment: I'm looking to comply with, I guess, whatever is on my machine which I think is 4.3

Comment: You're using depreciated functionality then (glBegin() and glEnd()). Try going through http://www.swiftless.com/ tutorials. It provides a good overview of 4.x compatibility programming.